# vscode terminal running cmd.exe loads the path incorrectly

Tags: windows, cmd, visual-studio-code, path, command-line-interface

I am running [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) on [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10). I've configured my [command-line-interface](/questions/tagged/command-line-interface) to be [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd).exe.

When I open up the the Command Prompt and look at the [path](/questions/tagged/path), I can see that it's changed `C:\Program Files\nodejs` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs`.

When I run `cmd.exe` directly, *(not inside vscode)*, the `PATH` is correct.

I know that Windows plays games with the `Program Files` directory, but I don't understand whats going on here.

Here is what I see when running `cmd` outside of `vscode`:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.1029]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\jeff>path
PATH=C:\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Python37\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\libnvvp;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\app\jefforacle\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;c:\jdk8u72\jdk1.8.0_72\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\apache-maven-2.0.9\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;L:\prj\defaults\code\bin;f:\apps\exec;L:\Prj\JavaDflts\code\BIN;C:\Program Files (x86)\AccuRev\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Users\jeff\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.1\lib;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Gradle\gradle-5.4.1\bin;C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin;C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Roaming\npm;

C:\Users\jeff>where node

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
```

And here is what I see when running inside vscode:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.1029]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\jeff>path
PATH=C:\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Python37\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\libnvvp;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\app\jefforacle\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;c:\jdk8u72\jdk1.8.0_72\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\apache-maven-2.0.9\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;L:\prj\defaults\code\bin;f:\apps\exec;L:\Prj\JavaDflts\code\BIN;C:\Program Files (x86)\AccuRev\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Users\jeff\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.1\lib;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Gradle\gradle-5.4.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin;C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Python37\;C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Roaming\npm

C:\Users\jeff>where node

INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

Comment: At a guess, VS Code launches a 32-bit command interpreter, whereas you are launching a 64-bit command interpreter.

Comment: Good thought!  I checked it out but both are running C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe. So that's not it.

Comment: `\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` is the location for 64-bit cmd.exe on Windows x64 and 32-bit cmd.exe on Windows x86. On Windows x64 the 32-bit cmd.exe path is `Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone in the future ends up scratching their heads over this particular problem, I’ve found another culprit, which blocked me for this particular problem on Windows:

[image: Showcase of setting]
Terminal>Integrated>Env: Enable Persistent Sessions

I suspect what happens is that after you update system paths, VScode caches the old path in the terminal and persists it, EVEN AFTER RESTARTING THE IDE! In this case it persists the old node path rather than the new node one.

Toggling this option off and restarting VSCode clears that cache, and the new path is loaded in. You can also toggle the option back on after you’re done.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.  You actually have to restart vscode after changing your path env variable in the system settings to get the new path in the cmd.exe running in the terminal window.

Stopping and restarting the terminal is not good enough.